# Symfony 2.7 choice_attr with EntityType field

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.7

I need to add an additional HTML attribute to each choice of an EntityType field in Symfony 2.7.

Following [this](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-choice-form-type-refactorization) guide, I assume that EntityType inherits this feature from ChoiceType. I tried something like the following, but without effect; no mytype attribute gets added to the rendered select options.

```
$builder->add('customer_email', 'email')
        ->add('Product', 'entity', array(
              'class' => 'MyBundle:Product',
              'property' => 'name',
              'empty_value' => 'None',
              'required' => false,
              'choice_attr' => function ($val, $key, $index) {
                  return array('mytype' => $val->getType());
              }))
```

Comment: your choice options elements don't have attribute "mytype"?

Comment: that's right. sorry, got this wrong in the question; edited it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not necessarily the best answer, but I can't post comments yet.

When implementing `choice_attr, choice_labels` etc... on ChoiceType and EntityType, it seems like `choice_attr` was left behind on the latter, there are a few comments about it on github, I personally need the same feature, hopefully it'll be implemented.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4067

**P.S.**: Investigated further, it is indeed inherited from ChoiceType, and it only appears in the 2.7 documentation, if you write something like

```
'choice_attr' => function (Product $product, $key, $index) {
    return ['class' => $product->getType() ];
}
```

You should get the class attribute set correctly, for custom attributes I am not sure, you might need to use `'attr' => 'foo'`.

**P.P.S**.: Tested `'foo' =>'bar'` and it works, no need to nest inside 'attr'.

Comment: OMG! Where did you find this in docs? I've spend hours searching for this in docs. Thnkx!!!